# PHP mysqli prepare Error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

First I need to say I have searched for OVER 2 Hours and did not find any answer that could help me! 
So here is my Question:
When every I try to execute that code:

```
    if(isset($_GET['name'])){ #Line 65
        $name = $_GET['name']; #Line 66
        $test = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM `SkyWars_Stats` WHERE player_uuid = ":name"'); #Line 67
        $test->bind_param(array('name' => $name)); #Line 68
        $test->execute(); #Line 69
    }
```

i get this Error:

> [Thu Sep 29 18:43:13.035006 2016] [:error] [pid 11506] [client **.**.***.***:*****] PHP Warning: Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt::bind_param() in /var/www/html/stats/index.php on line 68

Sooooo what did i do wrong?

Thank you for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you're using quotes inside a named placeholder:

```
WHERE player_uuid = ":name"
```

which need to be removed.

Then this is also PDO syntax also:

```
bind_param(array('name' => $name))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

However, you're using a `mysqli_` function here which does not support named placeholders, PDO does.

If you're connecting with the MySQLi_ API, then you need to use `?` placeholders.

If you are connecting with PDO, then you need to change the `bind_param()` to `bindParam()`.

Different MySQL APIs do not intermix.

For MySQLi_ syntax on prepared statements, consult:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
- Basic binding syntax `WHERE Name=?` --- `$stmt->bind_param("s", $city);`

---

For PDO syntax on prepared statements, consult:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php
- Basic binding syntax `VALUES (:name, :value)` ---  `$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);`

while using the same connection API for the respective functions.

- Your connection method/API is unknown.

Also make sure that your GET arrays contain values.

Check for errors via PHP:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

If you're getting these from a form, make sure it is NOT using POST method.

So, depending on the API you're using to connect with, you have the following to help you along to check for errors on the query:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php (MySQLi_)
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php (PDO)

Only *"you"* know which one is being used to connect with.

However, you did tag as `mysqli` here, so this suggests that you might be using the MySQLi_ API to connect with. If so, then follow the examples for it as shown above.

If it's `mysql_`, then that's an even bigger problem.

Comment: The problem is when I remove the quotes I would get a mysql error. Because the Name is no real name its something like this: 60595d66-25fc-4a0a-abfa-215cd514a6b3. And this does not work.

Comment: @Alexander again and as I stated in my answer, the MySQL API you're using to connect with is unknown. If it's `mysql_` or `mysqli_` or PDO; there is a big difference. The GET arrays are unknown also and if they contain values or not. I believe I have given you enough in my answer for you to continue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the double quoted string in the select statement

```
WHERE player_uuid = ":name"
```

> Mysqli `bind_param` is you need to pass the data type over to the bind parameter so that is executes the query along with bind params

mysqli_stmt::bind_param -- mysqli_stmt_bind_param — Binds variables to a prepared statement as parameters

**Object oriented style**

```
bool mysqli_stmt::bind_param ( string $types , mixed &$var1 [, mixed &$... ] )
```

**Procedural style**

```
bool mysqli_stmt_bind_param ( mysqli_stmt $stmt , string $types , mixed &$var1 [, mixed &$... ] )
```

Bind variables for the parameter markers in the SQL statement that was passed to`mysqli_prepare()`.

> `bind_param` arguments:

This is done using `$stmt->bind_param()`;

This function takes a minimum of two arguments.

1. The first is a string with information on the type of data.
2. The second is the variable that holds the data.

The information string can consist of the following characters only: **b, d, i, and s**. These stand for blob, double, integer, and string.

And you need to use the placeholder called `?` in the mysqli based rules and you are using `:name` which is totally out of track and you need to remove that.

**Example: using Mysqli bind_param**

```
$color = "purple";
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
if ($stmt->prepare("SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Friends
    WHERE FavoriteColor = ?")) {
       $stmt->bind_param("s", $color);
       $stmt->execute();
       $result = $stmt->get_result();
       while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
           //do stuff with the data in the $row array
       }
       $result->close();
}
```